# google api maps ms access lookup

Tags: ms-access, google-api, vba, postal-code

I have an MS Access database 2007 that records addresses manually.

I cannot afford the Post Office address finder therefore Google Maps or Places has been recommended to me.

I want to enter into a MS Access form either House number and postcode or just postcode that will query google and return the full address (Number, street, County and X Y coordinates etc) that I can then select and save to my table.

I do have VBA knowledge and have searched google extensively for examples but I am at a loss. I have also tried myself - but failed !!!

I am a complete novice in this area of using APIs, therefore any guidance or examples in this will be extreamly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have a read of this thread for an example https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=206247